# How do I combine 2 records with a single field into 1 row with 2 fields (Oracle 11g)?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here's a sample data

```
record1: field1 = test2
record2: field1 = test3
```

The actual output I want is

```
record1: field1 = test2 | field2 = test3
```

I've looked around the net but can't find what I'm looking for. I can use a custom function to get it in this format but I'm trying to see if there's a way to make it work without resorting to that.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use pivot:

```
with t(id, d) as (
  select 1, 'field1 = test2' from dual union all
  select 2, 'field1 = test3' from dual 
)
select *
  from t
pivot (max (d) for id in (1, 2))
```

If you don't have the id field you can generate it, but you will have XML type:

```
with t(d) as (
  select 'field1 = test2' from dual union all
  select 'field1 = test3' from dual 
), t1(id, d) as (
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d), d from t
)
select *
  from t1
pivot xml (max (d) for id in (select id from t1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this - google pivot rows to columns. Here is one set of answers: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm

Comment: It is more appropriate for a comment. At least you have to show some code and give some explanations.